# Some confusion about writing cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Hello I am having some trouble understanding exactly what I am doing when working with permutation groups and writing them as cyclic decompositions etc.

Here is an example which made me realize that I am not completely sure of what to do.

I wanted to multiply permutations in $S_{4}$

in particular $(423)(42)$

To me, I thought of this as $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 3 & 4 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

And so I thought, since we do composition, well 1 goes to 1 and 1 goes to 1 so that takes care of that,  2 goes to 4, and 4 goes to 2 etc, and so I thought the product would be

$$=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$ or (34)

.

But when I tried to work with wolfram, It gives me the answer of (23)

Which Is what I would get if I did mine in an opposite order.

So what is the correct order for composing permutations? Wouldn't I consider what is on the right first for example?

Thanks

Comment: Different books have different conventions on which direction the composition should go.  Check your source carefully and be aware that not all authors will use that same convention.

Comment: Curiously, although there is variation in which order the cycles are to be composed, everyone seems to agree on the directionality of the (disjoint) cycles themselves.  That is, (4 2 3) is a mapping of 4 to 2, 2 to 3, and 3 to 4.  I've not seen any disagreement about that convention.